# Drawing 3d diagram with some points in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a 3d diagram (with "Wireframe plots" or "Surface plots" or "Tri-Surface plots", but I don't want to draw "Scatter plots") by some points and i don't have any function. I checked the link: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/index.html#d-plotting but all the samples have a function for z that makes it continues but my data is just point. I mean, I have `x from 1 to 10 and y from 1 to 10`. I have points(totally 100 points) of `z for each x , y`. For example `z(1,2)=6, which x=1 , y=2`.
My question is, when we have some points in 2d area, we can draw a line or curve by plot function(matplotlin), is there any way that we draw a curve in 3d area by some 3d points?

Comment: Does your data describe triangles in 3D space? It sounds like there are continuous ranges of xy vals that map to a single z point, which I think means you have triangles. Either way, why can't you express your z values as a function of x and y? Sounds like you should be able to...

Comment: @duhaime No x,y are discrete and integer number from 1 to 10. I cant express z as a function of x , y because I get it from an optimization problem.

Comment: You need to create a quadrilangular grid. `X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,11), np.arange(1,11))`. And then just call `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z, ...)`.

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741050/how-to-draw-a-3d-diagram-in-python) twice. Instead, add an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with demo data and the code you tried.